# What is the maximum height that a siphon can work?

Tags: pressure, velocity, fluid-statics, flow, bernoulli-equation

Here is a photo from an article on [siphon](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siphon) in Wikipedia

[image]

My first question is what does maximum height of siphon mean? I mean which part of the siphon in below the photo would represent maximum height.

[image]

I think **CD** part represents maximum height , but I am not sure because some websites quotes **AB** as maximum height. Coming to my next doubt , if siphon is operating at its maximum height is the velocity of water in the siphon zero?

Comment: Are you familiar with Bernoulli's Principle?

Comment: Yes I am familiar with Bernoulli's principle

Comment: Then apply it and it will answer all your questions.

Comment: @Gert I need bit more clarification in maximum height. If we substitute 2nd equation (in 1st photo) in 1st equation then we will get velocity as zero. So siphon cannot work at this height . Then why should we say that this is the maximum height. Is this maximum height an approaching value ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the maximum height of that siphon as drawn is AB. Note that the maximum possible height of a water siphon is determined by the water pressure inside the raised portion of the siphon at its highest point, which will be below atmospheric. When that pressure equals the vapor pressure of water at whatever the ambient temperature happens to be, the water boils into vapor at the high spot and the siphoning action ceases.

Answer (score 0):

In practice, 22 feet is the highest a pump can suck water. A siphon faces a similar limit. I forgot the reference for the value it is over 50 years old. I sure of its correctness as pump pit for the well on the farm is 20 fe

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/428220)

Answer (score -1):

I believe AB is the maximum height here.
As can be seen, to drive the fluid up from A to B against gravity and have a gain in kinetic energy corresponding to velocity $v_b$ , there should be a drop in pressure from A to B in the light of Bernoulli's principle. The first equation that you have mentioned regarding the general height of the siphon takes the limiting case of Bernoulli's principle with pressure being 0 at B, in which case the liquid would vaporize spontaneously (as it would do in a hypothetical case of 0 atmospheric pressure). So that's what the maximum allowed height here is all about.

Comment: So in reality siphon cannot work with max. height as predicted by theoretical results.

Comment: Isn't the velocity of the water zero?

Comment: The pressure at B must be greater than zero. It must be at least as high as the vapor pressure of the liquid at whatever temperature.